# How do I force makecert to output the private key to a file (not the Crypto store)?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, cryptoapi, private-key, makecert

I want to generate a key pair for use within my applications, but exporting them manually from the mmc is a pain.

How can I use commandline parameters, or otherwise end up with a private certificate that resides on the hard drive, suitable for later distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28VS.80%29.aspx

Specifically, use the `-sv` option to save the private key to a file.